# Understanding NFS Server Load

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a Linux NFS server which has large number of clients. These clients mount a file, lock it and make low level file operations on it. As a result, server's load is low, but all locks are occupied and new clients cannot request even the smallest files.

I've increased the process count, everything is fine now, but I need a way to see the lock and thread state of the server.

Is there way to see such information for NFS?

**P.S.:** I've searched the site and didn't manage to find an answer. Sorry if it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFS server in the Linux kernel exports some statistics through the files in `/proc/net/rpc`. That file isn't self-documenting, however, and may be a bit cryptic.

There is a [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) plugin which parses it, however; that might help.